# TreeList for Angular 2

Tags: kendo-ui-angular2

Do you have plans for a Treelist widget for Angular 2. If yes, what is the ETA on such a widget? In the meantime is there a workaround to use the existing TreeList within an angular application?

Regards
Desmond

Answer (score 0):

TreeList (and the other high-level components) are scheduled for 2017. Further details are available in the [Kendo UI for Angular 2 Roadmap](http://assets.amuniversal.com/74a34eb09fc9012f2fe600163e41dd5b).

There are several known ways to make the current jQuery widgets run in Angular 2. None of them seems suitable for more complex scenarios, though, so I can't recommend going into this direction.

Answer (score 0):

You can use my own implement [tree component](https://github.com/NamNgKh/angular2_virtual_tree) for angular2+. It support a large tree, lazy loading and virtual scrolling